# TIdHTTP 10.6.2 Errors: Socket Error #11001 & #10051

Tags: indy, indy10, idhttp, c++builder-xe8

I really need your help again.

I trying to building a tiny download manager application by using TIdHTTP of Indy 10.6.2.5263 (shipped with XE8 Update 1) on C++ Builder XE8.

But, I always get errors `Socket Error #11001 - Host not found` when the target download address is `http://www.rarlab.com/rar/wrar53b1.exe`. Also, `Socket Error #10051 - Network is unreachable` when the download address is changed to `http://5.135.104.98/rar/wrar53b1.exe`.

I didn't know why I always keep getting those errors since all my other installed applications (Firefox, YM, [IDM](https://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/), etc..) are normally connected to Internet.

I'm using the following simple code.

`UNIT1.CPP`

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::DownloadClick(TObject *Sender)
{
   String FileName;
   String IB = InputBox("Download Manager", "Address", "");
   TFileStream* FStream = new TFileStream(FileName, fmCreate | fmOpenWrite);
    try
       {
        IdHTTP->ConnectTimeout = 1000;
        IdHTTP->ReadTimeout    = 1000;
        IdHTTP->Get(IB, FStream);
        ShowMessage("Download Complete");
       }
  __finally
     {
       delete FStream;
     }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::IdHTTPWork(TObject *ASender, TWorkMode AWorkMode, __int64 AWorkCount)
{
  if (ProgressBar->Max > 0)
  {
    DownloadStatus->Caption = IntToStr(AWorkCount) + "bytes of" + IntToStr(ProgressBar->Max) + "bytes.";
    ProgressBar->Position = AWorkCount;
  }
  else
    DownloadStatus->Caption = IntToStr(AWorkCount) + "bytes.";
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::IdHTTPWorkBegin(TObject *ASender, TWorkMode AWorkMode, __int64 AWorkCountMax)
{
  ProgressBar->Position = 0;
  ProgressBar->Max      = AWorkCountMax;
  if (AWorkCountMax > 0)
  DownloadStatus->Caption = "Transfering: " + IntToStr(AWorkCountMax);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::IdHTTPWorkEnd(TObject *ASender, TWorkMode AWorkMode)
{
 if (AWorkMode != wmRead)
   return;

 DownloadStatus->Caption = "Done";
 ProgressBar->Position = 0;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Works fine for me using 10.6.2.5293. It is probably a DNS lookup issue on your local network. Are you able to access those URLs using a web browser?  BTW, you cannot resume a broken download using `IdHTTP->Connect()` like you have shown. You must call `IdHTTP->Get()` to re-request the same URL again, specifying the desired range of bytes in the `IdHTTP->Request->Ranges` property, if the server supports ranges at all. Use the `IdHTTP->Response->AcceptRanges` property of the canceled download to check if `byte` ranges are supported. If not, you have to download the entire file from scratch.

Comment: I've tried to flushed my DNS resolver cache `[ipconfig /flushdns]` but nothing changes. There's no any problem to accessing any URL using my web browser. I've also updated my Indy to [Indy 10 Rev. 5274](http://www.mjfreelancing.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=13&Itemid=16), but still nothing changes. Can you look into it please ? Fyi, the `Indy10_5292` & `Indy10_5293's Fullc_XE8.bat` has unable to generate the `dclIndyxxx220.bpl`. Can you share the generated version of `Indy10_5293`?. Btw, about resuming broken downloads, i've been reading some articles about it. Thank you.

Comment: As I said, it works fine for me when I try it, the .exe file downloads as expected, so the problem has to be on your end. Have you tried using a packet sniffer, like Wireshark, to find out what is actually going on with the DNS/TCP packets? Do you have a firewall that is blocking the connections? And no, I am not going to share my BPL files. Are you sure `Fullc_XE8.bat` is not generating the BPLs, are you looking in the right output folder? Are you, by chance, running `Fullc_XE8.bat` with a 2nd input parameter set to a value other than `Win32`? That would skip compiling the `dcl...` packages.

Comment: I forgot to tell you something. The error has gone after I implement `catch(const EIdSocketError *ex)`, but but strangely, the download process does not run at all. Please let me know of your suggestions, if any. Thank you guys :)

Comment: All that is doing is hiding the error, not fixing it.  You need to find out what is actually going on with your network.

Comment: Okay. what about the `Indy10_5293` which failed to generate the 5 BPLs files ? Can you fix it or share the download link of the generated one ? Thank you.

Comment: The only pre-generated BPLs that are available are the ones that [Malcolm Smith provides](http://www.mjfreelancing.com/indy.htm). I can't fix the compile script without details about how it is failing.  Either post a new question with details about that, or email me privately (link to my site is in my [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau?tab=profile)).

Comment: Hi Remy Lebeau. I've been able to find the cause of the problem. So those errors occur because I am blocking the `Project1.exe` to access the Internet directly. Thank you guys.